# docbook-xsl Chunked HTML table of contents for each chapter

Tags: xslt, docbook

I've been reading the documentation all night and still can't figure it out.

How do I get the chunked output to include a ToC on the "front-page" of each chapter (and larger parts)?

Both the [DocBook-XSL documentation](http://docbook.sourceforge.net/release/xsl/1.78.1/doc/html/index.html) and [the online HTML version of "DocBook XSL: The Complete Guide"](http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/CustomizingPart.html) implement this, so at least I'm not entirely insane as far as it being at least possible…somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was staring me square in the face, I couldn't see the proverbial forest for all the trees I suppose.

Obviously, the parameter that controls this would be `generate.toc`, so after modifying my stylesheet to include—

```
<xsl:param name="generate.toc">
  appendix  toc
  book      toc,title
  chapter   toc
  part      toc
</xsl:param>
```

—it all rendered beautifully as one'd expect…